# CMSIS register values

Tags: arm, embedded, cpu-registers, cmsis

I have just started to explore the CMSIS for ARM controllers. It seems rather convenient to use it, however I was wondering where are the actual register values defined. Let's just take for example the GPIOs.

There is a structure GPIOA_AHB_Type defined with various members. Then, for GPIOB, there is a memory (or register?) address defined, let's say GPIOB_AHB_BASE. Afterwards, a pointer is set to GPIOB_AHB_BASE, like this:

```
#define GPIOB_AHB        ((GPIOA_AHB_Type*) GPIOB_AHB_BASE)
```

GPIOB_AHB's member variables as GPIOB_AHB->DIR for example, to set it input or output. My question is, where precisely are these member variables initialized? I guess the actual address of the registers is device specific, so I tried to find them in the device specific header, but all I found was the GPIOB_AHB_BASE define and the declaration of the member variables. How does the compiler know that when I type GPIOB_AHB->DIR, I want to write into the register that sets that port's I/O direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in your CMSIS header, you'll see all the structure definitions. Here's an example from my current project:

```
typedef struct
{
  __IO uint32_t DATA;              /*!< Port A Data Register                         */
  __IO uint32_t CR;                /*!< Port A Output Control Register               */
  __IO uint32_t FR1;               /*!< Port A Function Register 1                   */
  __IO uint32_t FR2;               /*!< Port A Function Register 2                   */
       uint32_t RESERVED0[6];
  __IO uint32_t OD;                /*!< Port A Open Drain Control Register           */
  __IO uint32_t PUP;               /*!< Port A Pull-up Control Register              */
       uint32_t RESERVED1[2];
  __IO uint32_t IE;                /*!< Port A Input Control Register                */
} TSB_PA_TypeDef;
```

Later on, a pointer to a structure of that type is defined:

```
#define PERI_BASE                  (0x40000000UL)
#define TSB_PA_BASE                (PERI_BASE  + 0x00C0000UL)
#define TSB_PA                     ((     TSB_PA_TypeDef *)    TSB_PA_BASE)
```

So that you can use it like:

```
TSB_PA->CR |= (1U << 2);          // make Port A, bit 2 an output
value = TSB_PA->DATA & (1U << 5); // read Port A, bit 5.
```

Comment: Thanks! So I see that the pointer TSB_PA points to a structure of type TSB_PA_TypeDef at the location TSB_PA_BASE. Within the structure however, how does the compiler know the individual location of DATA, CR, etc.?

Comment: It's a structure. They're all offset by the appropriate field sizes - that's why there are `RESERVED` fields in there - those are the holes in the memory map where there aren't any registers.

Comment: That makes sense :) In this case, I guess the order you declare the member variables matters as well, is that right?

Comment: They're not variables, they're fields in a structure. Yes, the order matters.

Comment: I've just googled it and now I see that structures are stored contiguously within the memory, so all that makes sense now. I don't see yet the difference between a variable and a field within the structure :-S...

Comment: @Botond : Contrary to Carl's comment, members of a structure are normally referred to as "members" in C rather than fields.  The term "field" *is* used in the context of Pascal "records", which are more-or-less analogous to C's `struct`.  In C++ where classes and structs can also have member *functions*, data members are normally referred to as "member variables", so I don't think you were so far off, but the membership is critical - they are not independent and do not exist outside of an instance of the struct.